# Does Mongo guarantee all writes occur if concurrency occurs?

Tags: mongodb

I have a lot of writes going on to the same field in Mongo and after reading the concurrency FAQ it sounds like it will queue the writes.

Therefore I was wondering if we had multiple writes on the same field, would I ever lose a write? or will the queue guarantee all writes occur?

Answer (score 0):

According to  [the FAQ](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/faq/concurrency/) :

> Blockquote
>   MongoDB allows multiple clients to read and write the same data. In order to ensure consistency, it uses locking and other concurrency control measures to prevent multiple clients from modifying the same piece of data simultaneously. Together, these mechanisms guarantee that all writes to a single document occur either in full or not at all and that clients never see an inconsistent view of the data.

So, logically, all write operations will occur and you won't lose any operations.